# Can i load a specific layout at runtime?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If my `orientation` changes, i don't want the entire layout to be re-loaded instead specific `section/layout` to be re-loaded/re-created for portrait mode.

**Update:**

I have placed this inside my mainifest => `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` , so the whole activity is not re-created again. But a certain section in my activity needs to be different for `potrait and landscape` mode.

Comment: your question is not clear. did you check the configChanges attribute in the manifest?

Comment: Please be specific a little provided info is not enough...

Comment: Check my updated part.

Comment: So what you want is a new layout for portrait but you don't want it to go through the activity lifecycle calls? I don't think you will be able to only re-load a specific area in the layout, you would need to load a new layout with that specific area changed from the landscape version.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `include layout`

***Eg:***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Now create separate `titlebar` layout in `res/layout`  and `res/layout-land`

For more see [Use the < include > Tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include)

Answer (score 1):

It's automatic. If you create a folder layout-land and create your new layout with the "same name"(If it's main.xml in layout folder than it should be main.xml in layout-land also). Then when android recreates your layout when orientation is changed to landscape, it will load the one under layout-land folder.

For further [information](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should let `Android` do its work. When the device rotate the Activity is destroyed and recreated. That means the `onCreate` is called. I will check the orientation inside the `onCreate` and choose the correct layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but when orientation is changed, your whole activity will be destroyed and reloaded, so every layout will be re-loaded.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `onConfigchange()`.

create two layout folder in `res` .

`layout_land` and `layout_port` and put these given xml's in these `layouts` .

Here you need to create two `layouts` with same name

1- `layout_change`

2- `layout_change`

in port add new change what you want .

Comment: That's what i am doing now, but i have placed the XML in my manifest so it won't load.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" when u place this in Manifest.xml, your orientation does not get loaded.

Comment: remove this line from manifest..why r u worrying about change activity will take care of that

Comment: That will re-load my entire activity, which i don't want... i want a specific part to get updated.

Comment: its little bit complicated ..you will have to use two layouts ...put some changes in port layout and call in onConfigchang ..with single layout might be not possible